# How to color rows of JTable according to particular value of attribute

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering

I have `JTable`, and I want the result in the table to have rows colored according to particular value of attribute; `comp` is `null` here:

```
private JNI18NTable _issueIncidentTable = new JNI18NTable(I18N_ID, COLUMNS, "issue.table.") {
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
            Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);

            int RangeIndex = Utilities.rowIndexToRangeIndex(_resultIter, row);
            Row theRow = _resultIter.getRowAtRangeIndex(RangeIndex);
            System.out.println("the row is" + theRow.getAttribute("Type"));
            boolean markRow = theRow != null && theRow.getAttribute("Type").toString().equals("c");
            boolean isSelected = isRowSelected(row);
            System.out.println("the comp" + comp);
            if (markRow) {
                comp.setForeground(Color.white);
                comp.setBackground(isRowSelected(row) ? Color.red.darker() : Color.red);
            } else {
                comp.setForeground(isSelected ? getSelectionForeground() : getForeground());
                comp.setBackground(isSelected ? getSelectionBackground() : getBackground());
            }
            return comp;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Extrapolating an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), your implementation of `prepareRenderer()` seems to work as shown below. You might look elsewhere in your code for the presumed problem. In particular, the implementation of `Utilities.rowIndexToRangeIndex()` should probably use the table's own *convert* method. Moreover, use the value of `isSelected` consistently.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20684058/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(10, 1) {

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return "Row " + row;
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
                Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);

                boolean isSelected = isRowSelected(row);
                if (row % 2 == 0) {
                    comp.setForeground(Color.white);
                    comp.setBackground(isSelected ? Color.red.darker() : Color.red);
                } else {
                    comp.setForeground(isSelected ? getSelectionForeground() : getForeground());
                    comp.setBackground(isSelected ? getSelectionBackground() : getBackground());
                }
                return comp;
            }
        };
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But comp is getting null again and again that is the problem here.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) & stack trace that exhibits the problem you describe.